# Jquery rollover issue no show me images right

Tags: jquery, mouseover, rollover

**I create these 2 codes the first code no works , show rollover bad , when for example i put over the first icon mouse over show me other icon no the first icon over , for example icon_1 and mouse over icon_1_down show me for example icon_5_down **

```
<script> 
$(function() {
    var number_menus = 9;
    for (i = 1; i <= number_menus; i++) {
        var p1 = +i;
        $(".wm_" + i).show().css("background-image", "url(imagenes/footer/m/" + i + ".png)");
        $(".wm_" + i).mouseover(function() {
            $(this).css("background-image", "url(imagenes/footer/m/" + i + "_down.png)");
            alert("this_down.png");
        });
        $(".wm_" + i).mouseout(function() {
            $(this).css("background-image", "url(imagenes/footer/m/" + i + ".png)");
        });
    }
});​
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
 <div id="web_footer_publi">
 <div id="web_footer_marks" class="wm_1"></div> <div
 id="web_footer_marks" class="wm_2"></div> <div id="web_footer_marks"
 class="wm_3"></div> <div id="web_footer_marks" class="wm_4"></div>
 <div id="web_footer_marks" class="wm_5"></div> <div
 id="web_footer_marks" class="wm_6"></div> <div id="web_footer_marks"
 class="wm_7"></div> <div id="web_footer_marks" class="wm_8"></div>
 <div id="web_footer_marks" class="wm_9"></div>
 </div>
```

**My second code works but when i go over the icons - when show these - have delay for show , more or less one second for show the icon over**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        $(".wm_" + i).show(1000).css("background-image", "url(imagenes/footer/m/" + i + ".png)");
    }
});
function footer(id) {
    $(function() {
        $(".wm_" + id).hover(function() {
            $(this).show().css("background-image", "url(imagenes/footer/m/" + id + "_down.png)");
        });
        $(".wm_" + id).mouseout(function() {
            $(this).css("background-image", "url(imagenes/footer/m/" + id + ".png)");
        });
    });
}​
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
 <div id="web_footer_publi">
 <div id="web_footer_marks" class="wm_1"
 Onmouseover="javascript:footer('1')"></div> <div id="web_footer_marks"
 class="wm_2" Onmouseover="javascript:footer('2')"></div> <div
 id="web_footer_marks" class="wm_3"
 Onmouseover="javascript:footer('3')"></div> <div id="web_footer_marks"
 class="wm_4" Onmouseover="javascript:footer('4')"></div> <div
 id="web_footer_marks" class="wm_5"
 Onmouseover="javascript:footer('5')"></div> <div id="web_footer_marks"
 class="wm_6" Onmouseover="javascript:footer('6')"></div> <div
 id="web_footer_marks" class="wm_7"
 Onmouseover="javascript:footer('7')"></div> <div id="web_footer_marks"
 class="wm_8" Onmouseover="javascript:footer('8')"></div> <div
 id="web_footer_marks" class="wm_9"
 Onmouseover="javascript:footer('9')"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, could you please format your code and HTML correctly? It's very hard to correct with all those `>` in front of your code.

Comment: You're using jQuery so you absolutely do not need to use any inline JavaScript events.

Comment: OK sorry but for me very difficult edit text in the tex editor of this website in my computer , regards

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. You can see in the console where its trying to find the images. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcTtv/1/)

```
$('#web_footer_publi div').each(function(){
    var itemNum = $(this).attr('class').replace('wm_','');
    $(this).css({'background-image':'url(imagenes/footer/m/' + itemNum   + '.png)'}) 
    $(this).mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).css({'background-image':'url(imagenes/footer/m/' + itemNum  + '_down.png)'})  
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css({'background-image':'url(imagenes/footer/m/' + itemNum   + '.png)'})  
    });
})​
```

Comment: Excuse me and why no works when i use loop as for ? , Regards